# GitLab PipeLine Cannot be created (Undefined Error)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am attempting to create my first (meaningful) child pipeline in GitLab.com and am suddenly coming across a meaningless error.

My parent pipeline has a job that create 5 identical child job files:

```yaml
empty:
  script:
  - 'echo ''Intentionally empty pipeline (0)'' '
variables:
  node: 0
```

These files are then executed by 5 identical trigger jobs:

```yaml
BuildSegment1:
  stage: compile
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: build/build.1.yml
        job: queuer
```

What's odd is that these trigger jobs fail at (seemingly) random. Sometimes 2 of them work, sometimes 3, somtimes 1. All failures give the same message:

> downstream pipeline cannot be created, Undefined Error

I'm a little befuddled by where to even start looking to solve this.

Comment: I'm not going to give this as an answer, because I don't think it is one. I think it turned out to be a YML error. The CI linter did not pick it up, but manually commenting everything out and bringing it back one instruction at a time magically made the issue go away.